# Compare value of a string to Database value

Tags: asp.net, database, arrays, string, compare

I have to compare a value in a string array to that of a particular column in a database. How do i do this ?

```
  public void setvisibility(string user_ID)
{
    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ctd_prrity_dbConnectionSting"].ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();\
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Admins );
```

I need to compare the value of user_ID to the only column in the Admins table !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
using( SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ctd_prrity_dbConnectionSting"].ConnectionString))
{ 
  connection.Open();   
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select 1 from Admins where User_ID=@userid",connection );
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid",user_ID);
  SqlDataReader reader= cmd.ExecuteReader();
  if(reader.HasRows)
  {
   //user id found
  }
}
```

This method uses a parametrized queries, which are safer than the option given in the answer by Tony since his is prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

BTW: you mention "string array" in your question, yet your code only shows a single string as parameter. What did you mean by that?

Comment: I am getting the user id    String userID = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1]; like this so it is essentially a string sorry for the confusion

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, are you getting the userID for the login on the machine? So for instance your windows user name is set up similar to "Domain\\userID" and you are just splitting on '\\' to take userID?

Comment: Yes that is Precisely Right.
This is what I get 
Error 2 'System.Data.IDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'HasRows' and no extension method 'HasRows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.IDataReader' could be found

Comment: @user1373852 interesting... I thought the IDataReader interface had this property defined but apparently, it is a property implemented in SQLDataReader. I updated my answer to reflect this: `SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();`

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlcommand("SELECT * FROM Admins WHERE column = " & user_ID );
```

That should work. What that does is it returns the value in the column if it is the same as the user_ID. Basically, if your query returns a value you have a match, if not then you don't.

Comment: And remember to sanitize all variables before passing to the database